# Webview error variations_seed (No such file or directory)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-webview

I tried to install my app in different versions of Android above 23 and it works perfectly.
I have the min sdk is 21 (Android 5.0) so I tried to test it in android 6.0 & 5.0 and I have the following error :

> E/cr_VariationsUtils: Failed reading seed file
>   "/data/user/0/**app_package**/app_webview/variations_seed":
>   /data/user/0/**app_package**/app_webview/variations_seed (No such file
>   or directory)

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the same issue(?),but may help someone else.

I had a similar issue on my Android app, error was coming from the ION library and the error msg was:

Failed reading seed file "/data/user/0/{package name}/app_webview/variations_seed_new": /data/user/0/{package name}/app_webview/variations_seed_new (No such file or directory)
2021-12-10 15:30:56.177 15083-15225/{package name} E/libEGL: validate_display:99 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)

And the solution (for me) was to update the ION version I was using.

I had:  implementation 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:3.0.4'

and the fix was to change it to:

implementation 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:3.1.0'

Answer (score -1):

because android latest version androidx does not consist such file so search for that file that file in androidx library

Comment: I'm not using Androidx

Comment: but android 3.5 version and above required androidx  library

Comment: I simply used  the tradional Android support library for some reasons ..

Answer (score -1):

Are you noticing any crashes in your app or any ANRs?

You don't need to worry about these logs errors, they are internal errors in WebView and they should not affect your app.

Comment: Actually the app crashes for this issue

Comment: I still think these particular logs aren't why the app is crashing, it's WebView trying to read a file for its internal feature managing and it should be fine. Can you provide more logs? a code snippet for how you setup your WebView? that would be helpful.